# what is the cause of this error: Structure required on left side of . or .*?

Tags: c, structure

```
typedef struct tsk{
    int x;
    int n;
}TSK;

TSK trd[MAX];
 main(){
    while(life!=0){
 randomize();
     for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){
     trd[i].n=rand()%40+10;
         if(trd[i].n<10||trd[i].n>45)
         trd[i].n=rand()%40+10;
         trd[i].x=25;
     }
     for(m=0;m<MAX;m++){
     gotoxy(8,m);printf("%c%c",23,23);
     gotoxy(7,m);printf("%c",17);
     gotoxy(46,m);printf("%c%c",23,23);
     gotoxy(48,m);printf("%c",16);
     }
 for(j=0;j<MAX;j++){
 if(life==0)
     break;
 gotoxy(1,1);
 insline();
 gotoxy(trd[j].n,1);
 printf("%c",3);
 trd[j].x--;
 gotoxy(ply,25);
 printf("%c",1);
 gotoxy(1,26);
 delline();
 score++;
 life=hit(trd,life,ply);
 gotoxy(57,25);
 printf("SCORE: %0.0f  LIFE: %d",score,life);
 gotoxy(8,1);printf("%c%c",23,23);
    gotoxy(46,1);printf("%c%c",23,23);
    gotoxy(7,1);printf("%c",17);
    gotoxy(48,1);printf("%c",16);
    gotoxy(4,1);printf("%c",label[j]);
    delay(200);

        if(kbhit()){
            key=getch();
            key=toupper(key);
            if(key==27)
                life=0;
            if(key=='L')
            ply++;
                if(ply==46)
                ply--;
            else if(key=='K')
            ply--;
                if(ply==9)
                ply++;
            }
   }
  }
}

int hit(int trd[],int life, int ply){
int i;
    for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){
        if((trd[i].n==ply)&&(trd[i].x==0))
            life-=1;
        }
    return life;


  }
```

Can anyone help me how to correct this error: Structure required on left side of . or .*? when i run the program, it gives me this error and it is pointing to hit() function. i can't find what causes this error.pls help.thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a compile-time error, not a run-time error. It happens because you are attempting to access `.x` and `.y` on elements of an array of type `int[]`. Integers are not `struct`s, they do not have fields `x` and `y`, so compiler tells you it's an error.

The most likely fix should be changing the type of `trd` array parameter of the `hit` function as follows:

```
int hit(TSK trd[],int life, int ply) {
    ...
}
```

Note that since you are using the function before declaring it, you should add a prototype at the top.

Answer (score 6):

`trd` is an `int` array. `int` has no member `n` or `x`.

Fix the function signature to `int hit(TSK trd[], int life, int ply)`

Answer (score 2):

In your `hit` function, the `trd` argument is an array of `int`s.  Did you mean to make the argument of type `TSK[]` instead?